# Creating double boxplots- i.e two boxes for each x-value

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot diagram where each x-value has two boxplots right next to each other, kinda like this:

[image]

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Drawing does not help searches so relevant things to call it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if there is a name for this kind of plot but you can create this simply by using the `pyplot.boxplot` function and passing in the positions keyword to shift the boxes slightly. Here is an example

```
x = np.array([1000,2000])
data1 = np.array([np.random.normal(loc=0.5,size=100),np.random.normal(loc=1.5,size=100)]).T
data2 = np.array([np.random.normal(loc=2.5,size=100),np.random.normal(loc=0.75,size=100)]).T
plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(data1,0,'',positions=x-100,widths=150)
plt.boxplot(data2,0,'',positions=x+100,widths=150)
plt.xlim(500,2500)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.show()
```

First we create the two sets of data for the left and right boxes and the corresponding *x* locations. Next we plot each set of data specifying the position to be *x* but shifted left and right slightly respectively. *Note: Because our x positions are far apart we also have to adjust the widths using the `widths` keyword.* Now we set the correct x-axis limits and then finally replace the x-tick locations with the ones we want.

It produces this output:

[image]